# Is it possible to define the class of functions $\phi: [1,\infty)\rightarrow[0,0.6)$ with infinite product which converges to $0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, infinite-product

Consider $\phi: [1,\infty)\rightarrow[0,c)$ for some constant $c=0.6$. I am wondering if there are any required properties of $\phi$ such that
$$\prod_{i=0}^{\infty} (1-\phi(i))=0.$$

I assume defining asymptotics, such as Big O notation would be desirable. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Under the global assumption that the sequence $\{\phi(k)\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ ranges in $[0,1)$, the assertion on the product is equivalent to $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\phi(k)=\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\ln(1-x)/\ln(0.4)$, which is a bijection $f\colon[0,0.6)\to[0,1)$. Now, letting $\psi(i)=f(\phi(i))=\ln(1-\phi(i))/\ln(0.4)$, you see that $\prod_{i=0}^\infty(1-\phi(i))$ converging to $0$ is equivalent to $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\psi(i)$ diverging to $\infty$, with $\psi(i)\in[0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is great! How could the $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{k}\psi\left(i\right)=\infty$ condition be proven rigorously?

Comment: That is equivalent to: for every real number $B>0$ there exists an integer $N>0$ such that for all $k>N$, we have $\sum_{i=0}^k\psi(i)>B$. However, not much more can be said about this, since there are simply too many sequences $\psi(i)$ with $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\psi(i)=\infty$. (e.g., $\psi(i)=0.3$, $\psi(i)=1/(i+1)$, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, the equivalent form is helpful. I meant is there a rigorous proof for Saucy O'Path's comment (which seems to be a lemma in your argument) or is it a well-known result?

Comment: $\prod_{i=0}^k(1-\phi(i))\to0\ (k\to\infty)$ iff $\sum_{i=0}^k\ln(1-\phi(i))\to\infty\ (k\to\infty)$ iff $\sum_{i=0}^k\psi(i)\to\infty\ (k\to\infty)$.